# Changes in Kinetic Energy

Tags: energy

> A body is moving with a constant speed on a circular path. What happens to its Kinetic energy?

Kinetic energy is dependent on velocity but Kinetic energy on the whole is a scalar so direction does not matter. I am in doubt as to the answer of this question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are correct, kinetic energy will be constant

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: Why do you doubt that your answer is correct? You have not provided any reason.

Comment: Actually I was not sure if Kinetic Energy was a vector or a scalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinetic energy is independent of the velocity's direction, so it depends only on its magnitude:
$$ K = \frac{1}{2} m \, v^2 $$

In uniform circular motion, the magnitude of the velocity does not change, even though its direction is changing at every point. Hence, the kinetic energy of the particle in motion remains constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was completely unaware that Kinetic energy does not depend on the direction of velocity.